# Excel VBA Only Executes Highlight Cell in Break Mode

Tags: vba, excel

I wrote a macro for ExcelVBA that is extremely simple. It essentially copies the entire section of the sheet over, and then adds 4 to the cell selected by the user.

My challenge is with the end - I want to highlight the cell I added 4 to. 
I select the cell and paste in the value:

```
With Progression.Cells(CatSearch, CurrentColumn)
    .Value = LF
    .Interior.ColorIndex = 37
End With
```

Problem is that it changes the value of the cell, but not the color.

Interesting point is that it works in break mode, but not when I run the entire macro.

```
Public Sub BuildFootageProgression()

Dim Category As Byte
Dim Working As Workbook
Dim Progression As Worksheet

Set Working = ActiveWorkbook
Set Progression = Working.Sheets(1)


Category = InputBox("Enter Category Number of Category to Gain Next Four Feet", "Category Decision Box")
''Asks which category should gain the next four feet in a popup box


Dim CatSearch As Integer
Dim InputResult As String
CatSearch = 1


'Start by verifying that the input category is in the list, and identifies the row # of that category and saves to variable "Cat Search"

Do Until Sheet1.Cells(CatSearch, 1).Value = Category
    CatSearch = CatSearch + 1

    If CatSearch > 10000 Then
        InputResult = InputBox("The previously entered category number could not be found. Enter Category Number of Category to Gain Next Four Feet.", "Category Decision Box")

        If InputResult = vbNullString Then
            Exit Sub
        Else
            Category = InputResult
            CatSearch = 1
        End If
    End If
Loop


'This section is to find the first blank column and identify the 12 columns we will be working with
If Sheet1.Cells(CatSearch, 1).Value = Category Then

    Dim CurrentColumn As Integer
        CurrentColumn = 1

    Do Until IsEmpty(Cells(1, CurrentColumn))
    CurrentColumn = CurrentColumn + 1
    Loop


End If

'Function to copy formula from previous section to current section
Dim previous As Range
Set previous = Range(Sheet1.Cells(1, CurrentColumn - 11), Sheet1.Cells(100, CurrentColumn - 1))
previous.Copy (Sheet1.Cells(1, CurrentColumn))

Dim Current As Range
Set Current = Range(Sheet1.Cells(1, CurrentColumn + 1), Sheet1.Cells(100, CurrentColumn + 10))
Current.Columns.AutoFit

'Unhighlights all of the cells
For Each c In Current.Cells
    c.Interior.ColorIndex = 2
Next

'Adds four feet to chosen category
Dim LF As Integer
LF = Sheet1.Cells(CatSearch, CurrentColumn).Value
LF = LF + 4

With Progression.Cells(CatSearch, CurrentColumn)
    .Value = LF
    .Interior.ColorIndex = 37
End With


'Takes Null Values and Makes the Cells Blank
Cells.Replace "#N/A", "", xlWhole

End Sub
```

Comment: I'm not familiar with CatSearch / CurrentColumn. Do either of those look at the most recently changed cell? My only experience with getting different results when executing via break mode vs 'regularly running' is that breakmode sometimes keeps a different sheet/cell "active" because it 'activates' a different sheet if the code being run is underneath that sheet's module.

Comment: the code snippet you have above your code sample does not match the code you posted. In the posted code, you exclude setting the color.

Comment: Okay I went and added it!!

Comment: Which Excel version? I can remember there are some issues with the `ColorIndex` in older versions.

Answer (score 0):

```
Sub Color()
  Dim myRange As Range
  Set myRange = Range("B1")
  myRange.Interior.ColorIndex = 22
End Sub
```